# How to Create Dynamic Multithreading with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, multithreading, websocket, socket.io, child-process

I want to implement multithreading in socket.io in my project; earlier, I launched a single node app on my server, which required a high level of CPU consumption for a period of time, and I was experiencing memory leaks in my code, which I have now reorganized.

**I have a few questions:**

- Is multithreading supported by socket.io?
- Is my CPU properly utilised if I use multithreading in my node app?
- How can I make several threads in my Node.js app?

> Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Node doesn't support multithreading, does it?